# Is the wingtip fence as effective as the winglet?

Tags: airliner, winglets, wing-tip-vortex

My guess would be no because it does not reflect the air as well.[image]Wingtip fence

[image]Winglet

What I am basically asking is does the wing tip fence have the same amount of drag reduction (wing tip vortex) as the winglet?

Comment: @Ethan, you may want to consider doing a bit more research (either searching here, or searching the web) if you don't want people to downvote or vote-to-close your questions.